# Node.js and Socket.IO Not Responding in Some Servers

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nodejitsu

I have simple Node.js and Socket.IO app running on Nodejitsu. The App is running perfectly from home and some other Internet services but not working from my work!

Here is the error Message which I am getting

```
 The connection to ws://behseini-socketproject.jit.su/socket.io/1/websocket/QtVm6E79WwGLwBVjN7el was interrupted while the page was loading.
 this.websocket = new Socket(this.prepareUrl() + query);

 socket.io.js (line 2371)
 GET http://behseini-socketproject.jit.su/socket.io/1/?t=1370531712581      200 OK
                                                                    535ms   
 socket.io.js (line 1659)
 ParamsHeadersResponse

 fPtjDNnugmPPXKbnN7ep:60:60:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening? is this kind of Firewall issue?

Thanks

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess I'd say it's a proxy issue, as far as how to fix it I'm not really sure. But that is the first place I'd look.

Comment: Thanks Travis, that is my first guess too but I am not sure how to deal with it either!

Comment: Is it always happening, or spontaneously?

Comment: Hi Sly yes it is always happening in the office. As I said it is working perfectly other paced but not on here!

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same problem. I have developed a real time application with socket.io + node.js and it is working very fine on my network, but simply fails on my client network. On my client system I get the same problem as mentioned by you above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with you on the #nodejitsu IRC channel, it seems that this may indeed be a problem with your work proxy/firewall.

As was suggested to you in the chat last night, you could always try to use secure websocket connections (wss rather than ws) to see if that will allow your connections to pass through.

If that doesn't work, you would need to send your connection outside of your work's connection. For instance, proxying into a computer at your home and using your home network while you're at work and want to use websockets.

Comment: Thanks Sly, it was useful just as always :-) I need to find some tutorial for doing this, however. I am not good at network things!